# Has a hostile submarine transitted the Bosphorus submerged?

Tags: naval, cold-war

In WW1, the British submarine [E-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_E11) entered the Golden Horn, but apparently not the Bosphorus, and in [this old thread on Usenet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/submarine$20bosphorus$20russians/sci.military.naval/Iu7ab68jnJ8/FECALfOUlrYJ) there are references to WW1 and fiction.

According to [a recent article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.wneu.2012.11.004) in *World Neurosurgery*, the American submarine [Robert E. Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Robert_E._Lee_(SSBN-601)) passed through the Bosphorus submerged in 1969:

> patrols based out of Holy Loch, Scotland, that involved clandestine
>   courses that required passage through the Straits of Gibraltar,
>   Mediterranean Sea, Dardanelles, and Bosphorus. Each of these
>   accomplishments was achieved submerged [...] The Bosphorus passage was
>   particularly treacherous and irregular, with complex positioning and
>   course changes that were affected by currents and the presence of
>   Soviet submarine traffic and planned impediments.

[image: map]

(We ignore that the map shows a route straight through [Perekop isthmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isthmus_of_Perekop). The Bosphorus is what interests us here.)

The reference to "Soviet submarine traffic" seems to suggest this was not regulated traffic. The [Montreux convention](http://sam.baskent.edu.tr/belge/Montreux_ENG.pdf) says that "submarines must travel by day and on the surface". On the other hand, surely NATO/Turkey would have been able to detect submarines in the Bosphorus in 1969?

Am not sure it would have been practical to do it with the technology available in WW 1/2.

So the question is: are there any records of any submarines not friendly to Turkey passing through the Bosphorus submerged?

Comment: Given that the depth of the Bosphorus is just 13m at a given point ( around Aşiyan/Besiktas), that seems rather unlikely/risky.

Comment: The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosphorus) seems to say it is shallow only on one side. A sub doesn't have to follow the boat lanes. Also, it is presumably only that shallow for a short distance.

Comment: I don't believe the story in that *American Neuroscience* article. The Robert E. Lee was a ballistic missile submarine, and a significant part of the US nuclear deterrent at the time. Its job was to be not found, not to risking getting caught going through those straits.

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me also, but [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Robert_E._Lee_(SSBN-601)) she was based in Holy Loch in 1967-1971. The straits (Gibraltar & Dardanelles/Bosphorus) are NATO territory. Or maybe it was just a different sub.

Comment: I'm a bit too pushed for time to put together a dceent answer, but this page on [Daring the Dardanelles](http://www.public.navy.mil/subfor/underseawarfaremagazine/Issues/Archives/issue_08/daring_dardanelles.html) seems to suggest that British / Australian submarines managed it during WW1

Comment: @User999999: The [Kadettrinne](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadetrinne) is only 10-30m deep, very hard to navigate, and sees tens of thousands (!) ships passing through it per year. Yet still U-Boats are passing it routinely. Actually, that very passage is the reason modern German and Danish subs are *designed* so they can go submerged in as little as 17m depth...

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not saying it's impossible, just saying it's unlikely.  i'm merely stating that the risks involved would pose a serious challenge for any subcommander/navigator. If someone did manage to do this, then I believe we should look in the WW1 - WW2 era, as subs tend to be smaller then.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: that is discussed in the usenet thread linked earlier. This was the closest they got: "E-11 was suddenly caught up in the confused welter of cross-currents and density layers just south of the Bosphorus [...]" (apparently).

Comment: @User999999: smaller yes, but also a lot less capable. It seems likely the cold war russians would have been doing it as much as they could get away with. But details, please.

Comment: Not cold-war related, but post-WW1 related.Look at page 96. There the United Kingdom tries to cross the bosphorus submersised  [google books link] (https://books.google.be/books?id=ruqqCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=bosphorus+submarine&source=bl&ots=yLfWlvX5rf&sig=6AMvCxQUSWMvKtY_a5eViSmJIzU&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ_Ly3oOnZAhWHJMAKHceMAvo4ChDoAQguMAE#v=onepage&q=bosphorus%20submarine&f=false)

Comment: [HMAS AE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAS_AE2) got into the Sea of Marmara, but not the Bosphorus. It "ran amok" for 5 days trying to fool the Turks into thinks there were a number of foreign submarines in the region.

Answer (score 9):

Information provided by [user999999](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/17186/user999999).

According to [Halpern, *The Mediterranean Fleet, 1919–1929*, p. 96](https://books.google.be/books?id=ruqqCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=bosphorus%20submarine&source=bl&ots=yLfWlvX5rf&sig=6AMvCxQUSWMvKtY_a5eViSmJIzU&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ_Ly3oOnZAhWHJMAKHceMAvo4ChDoAQguMAE#v=onepage&q=bosphorus%20submarine&f=false), the British submarine [HMS E46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_E46) made a passage in 1919 at periscope depth (or slightly above), and concluded submerged transit undetected would not be possible/practical.

[image]

Addition, context: in 1919 Istanbul was [occupied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupation_of_Constantinople) by the WWI victors, so this does not really count as a "hostile" passage.

Answer (score 0):

[June 23, 2020](https://nationalinterest.org/blog/buzz/did-russia-just-send-submarine-through-bosphorus-163321)

> In [a Twitter post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200623171908/https://twitter.com/YorukIsik/status/1275468794987712514), a respected Turkish ship spotter showed
> evidence that a Russian Kilo-class submarine allegedly passed through
> the Bosphorus, in violation of the Montreux Convention. At press time,
> we were unable to confirm the report independently, however, if true,
> the news would be very significant.

(Apparently it sailed on the surface.)